# webpack-dev-server - serve gzipped bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've added the [CompressionPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/compression-webpack-plugin) to my webpack config.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
  entry: {
    app: './app.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/src')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/,
        use: ['url-loader?limit=10000']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      favicon: 'favicon.ico',
      template: 'index.html'
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: /\.(js|html)$/,
      deleteOriginalAssets: true
    })
  ]
}
```

Now instead of my `app.bundle.js` I have an `app.bundle.js.gz`. That's correct.

However inside my index.html I'm still using the `app.bundle.js` path.

How do I tell [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) to serve the gzipped file when the browser requests `app.bundle.js`? In production proper web servers like Apache or nginx can do this.

Comment: Can't you use [`devServer.compress`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-compress) instead?

Comment: We're not using the dev server in production. We want to build a gzipped bundle and ship that to our production server. We could gzip after bundling with webpack but I thought there is a built in solution.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated: `webpack-dev-server` doesn't serve the bundle file per se, it serves the bundle from memory. But you can always disable `CompressionPlugin` when running in development mode.

Comment: If you wanna have the points for this answer just go ahead and post it as one. I will accept it tomorrow if there aren't any other solutions.

Comment: @zemirco, Facing the same issue, any update?